# Configuring a Mule ObjectToInputStream transformer

Tags: mule

The Mule 'Using Transformers' documentation lists many out-of-the-box transformers, among them ObjectToInputStream and ObjectToString:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Transformers

For ObjectToString, it can be configured for example like this:

```
<object-to-string-transformer name="object-to-string" />
```

but the corresponding does not work for ObjectToInputStream :

```
<object-to-input-stream-transformer name="object-to-input-stream" />
```

How can the ObjectToInputStream-transformer be configured, and what is it's default 'name'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mule hasn't provided the config tag for this transformer.

But the transformer is already available in the mule basic transformers.
Try it this way.

```
<custom-transformer class="org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToInputStream"></custom-transformer>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look right to me to use the 'custom-transformer '-element to configure a transformer provided out-of-the-box by Mule. Does the ObjectToInputStream have a standard name that i can refer to from a 'transformer-refs'-attribute?

Comment: As of my knowledge, no.  Mule has provided the transformer, but is not loading the class. We have to load it to use it.

Comment: While this wasn't the answer i hope for, the suggestion certainly works.